# Time Series Seasonality and Frequency

Tags: time-series, python, seasonality, frequency, pandas

I am working with a time series that indicates the number of times a user logs into an application per minute. I want to find an algorithmic way (in Python) that would detect if there is any pattern in this measurement in the following sense: say a user logs in an extremely high number of times every 5 minutes. How can I detect this frequency of high numbers of log-ins?

I tried using seasonality for this, and splitting the time series into seasonal components, but I don't know how to automatically use these in order to find what I am looking for.